# How to arrange Label, Entry in TabbedPanel in python using Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Hello I am facing problem when I am using a GUI in python using Kivy. I am using TabbedPanel.

```
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'apple'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Label1'
            Entry:
                text: 'Entry1'
            CheckBox: 
                text: 'CheckBox1'
            Button:
                text: 'Button1'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Grape'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Label1'
            Button:
                text: 'Button1'
```

Comment: You have an error in your kv: `Entry` is not a kivy class, it must be `TextInput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

- you can have only one build method
- return in the second build method, is incorrectly indented, should be same as `for`
- you can always only have one App class not `class AccordionApp(App):` and `class KivyGuiApp(App):`

Here is a smaller version of your app from which you should be able to implement more from

```
'''
TabbedPanel
============

Test of the widget TabbedPanel.
'''

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App


Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'apple'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Label1'
            Label:
                text: 'Entry1'
            CheckBox: 
                text: 'CheckBox1'
            Button:
                text: 'Button1'

""")

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class KivyGuiApp(App):

    def build(self):
        test = Test()
        acc = Accordion()
        for x in range(5):
            item = AccordionItem(title='Table %d' % x)
            item.add_widget(Button(text='apple\n'))
            item.add_widget(Button(text='Grape\n'))
            item.add_widget(Button(text='Lemon\n'))
            acc.add_widget(item)
        panel = TabbedPanelItem()
        panel.add_widget(acc)

        test.add_widget(panel)
        return test



if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyGuiApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it helped or solved your question.

Comment: I'll have some time this evening (UK time) and will take a look. You'll have to wait until then, sorry. If I should do something with the txt files as well, please make them accessible to me.

Comment: hey @PalimPalim, can you help me with those issues? Thanks in advance

Comment: i just tried your app. It is a lot of work for me to understand your code and than edit something and also understand what you would like to achieve. Isn't it posssible to seperate out your issues into smaller problems and post each one as a question. Best is if you have a sample app which has the minimum amount of code neccessary.